# Как добавить SSL к домену. Next.JS VPS(Node.JS) Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ssl, vps, next.js

Прошу помощи. Сколько не штудировал англоязычный интернет, так и не нашел, какого-то вменяемого руководства, как добавить SSL к приложению на Next.js, которое находится на VPS.
Что пробовал:

1. Создавал сервер на чистой убунте, через Ngnix деплоил Next.js, Туда успешно подключал SSL от домена, но на ngnixe возникали сначала ошибки с отображением изображений, исправил. Отвалилось отображение видео...Бросил затею.
2. Поднял сервер на убунте с просто Node.js, там задеплоился, сделал перенаправление с порта, все в порядке, все работает, НО SSL я так и не понял, как поставить. Делал сервер на Express, пытался через него подключить сертификаты, но браузер ругается, что сайт не безопасен, сертификаты выданы для домена, а не для локалхоста. Через OpenSSL выпустил сертификаты для локалхоста, тоже не пускает...
3. Нашел для себя спасение на ДиджиталОушене, но кириллические домены там не работают. ( в паникоде тоже )
4. Vercel не предлагать.
5. Вернулся к Убунте с Node.js.

Так вот, кто-нибудь может подсказать, как подключить сертификаты на VPS с нодой.

Comment: Вернуться к п.1, разобраться с ошибками и настроить правильно.

Comment: 2 - таки непонятно как настраивали и как пытались открыть. 3 - не верю.

Comment: 3 Пункт можете проверить)

Comment: Я в такой ситуации поднял nginx, на нём настроил proxy_pass к серверу на node.js по http. Все сертификаты развёрнуты в nginx. Для этого есть удобный скрипт `certbot`, который автоматически устанавливает бесплатные сертификаты Let's Encrypt